# What happens to the cell during post-hypothermia?

Tags: physiology

A friend of mine said that the cell membrane somehow changes after rewarming from hypothermia and that the body does not recognize it's own cells, thus leads the immune system to attack it self. Is this true? And do anyone know how/why the cell changes?

Comment: interesting question - we use therapeutic hypothermia in critically ill patients following cardiac arrest  commonly in the hospital - I've seen patients wake after 48h of hypothermia and have no long term effects (at least that are detectable) - not sure how things change on a cell membrane level or whether or not this has been studied in  patients

Comment: here is a link to a open access paper from the journal Circulation that discusses therapeutic hypothermia and how long/how cold we keep people - as well as a discussion of whether or not we should cool people longer and/or colder... should be useful for this question... http://circ.ahajournals.org/content/131/7/669.long